# Redirected you too many times error

Tags: c#, asp.net, global-asax

using asp.net webforms,iis 7.5
this error occurs on specific ip's after 5,6 days.currently its working everywhere but shows this error on some specific ip's.Tried reseting browsers,but seems there is something wrong in my code.Also another application hosted on same ip with different port is also having same issue.

**Error**:
The 111.111.111 page isn’t working

111.111.111.111 redirected you too many times.
Try clearing your cookies.
ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS

**my global.asax:**

```
if (HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.ToString().ToLower().Contains("http://111.111.111.111/Default.aspx"))
{  
    HttpContext.Current.Response.Status = "301 Moved Permanently";
    HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Location", Request.Url.ToString().ToLower().Replace("http://111.111.111.111", "http://www.abcd.com"));
}
```

Comment: From what I read this error is about getting redirected over and over without stopping anywhere. What more is there to the code? Is there an else-statement? Check this article: http://techwelkin.com/how-to-solve-this-webpage-has-a-redirect-loop-problem

Comment: Well it's tough to point it in correct way.  Have you tried checking network log and evetviewer to get the idea about what is happening.  Hope it helps

Comment: @actually initially my site was showing ip in url , so i just added this code in my global.asax, after that the application redirects ip to domain successfully , but after a period of every 5,6 days this issue happens on some ip's. and it happend after adding this code.

Comment: Well, in this case I suppose you want to redirect IP-based request to domain-based request for `Default.aspx` to show domain name in address bar, but some clients failed to recognize the difference between those requests and causing infinite request to `Default.aspx` page.

Comment: @TetsuyaYamamoto , i didnt get how its possible, since its happening on my own system also, and some time it loads succussfully , but what happens after 5,6 days.and this error automatically removes after 6,7 hours and then the site works fine.

Comment: also if i remove this code from my global and the upload dll then the site works fine , but it shows ip in url.

Comment: At this point, you may need a DNS server or IIS site binding by entering custom domain name to change IP-based request automatically into domain name. IMHO, redirecting IP address request to custom domain using response headers is not a good idea due to possibility of infinite request issue.

Comment: @Danieboy there is no else , this is the only statement in application_beginrequest ..